# Node.js Cheerio Live Update/Instant Refresh page on every HTML body change

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, cheerio

I am using **Axios** and **cheerio** to scrape the cricket score website and convert its data to JSON format.
But the problem is that scores and other information are not updating instantly on my API response.
I want to have kind of **useEffect** (I know, it's React Hook and don't work in Express) functionality in my express server so that whenever the score changes on the main website, my server re-scrapes the page and show updated data.

```
axios(link).then(response => {
        const html = response.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const score = []

        $('.scorecard-container', html).each(function(){
            const title = $(this).text()
            const url = link + $(this).find('a').attr('href')
            score.push({
                id: score.length + 1,
                title,
                url
            })
        })
        res.json(score)
    }).catch(err => {res.send('Something went wrong'); console.log(err)})
```

*Thanks in Advance* :)

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense because cheerio isn't a browser, it's just a parser.

Comment: I am just asking how can I reparse the updated info

Comment: You would make a new request and do it the same way

Comment: How can I? Should I have to do it using recursion or it could be done by other methods?

Comment: Why would you need recursion?

Comment: If you need to do this in real time and periodically polling the URL with axios isn't fast enough, consider using browser automation like Puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

example express endpoint

```
get("/stats", async (req, res) => {
  let { data } = await axios.get(someUrl)
  let $ = cheerio.load(data)
  res.json({
    title: $('title').text()
  })
})
```

in react

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/stats").then(r=> r.json().then(data => setStats(data)))
}, [])
```